# How to start a flask server on android/iOS in backend

Tags: python, android, flask

I am making an app with flutter frontend and python backend. The problem is that I need to create a flask server running offline locally on an Android or iOS device. I don't know how to start the server simultaneously with the app to push some http requests to the server.

The server is basically:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import socket
import threading
import paramiko

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/function_name', methods=['POST'])
def function():

....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809214/running-an-android-phone-as-a-stable-webserver-for-a-python-cgi-script) may be appropriate answer, but it's still very uncommon and I think you will have problems with that. Is there any reason you do not start your server on local machine and use 192.168.X.X network?

Comment: This is just a sketch. I just wanted to provide some code for better understanding. The big deal for now is the principle itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that although not recommended as it may consume a lot of resources.

Install Pydroid 3 app from play store. In the app install flask by typing

```
pip install flask
```

write your app and run 'python app.py' or whatever name your app is called

on your phone browser, use http://localhost:5000 and here you go.

On ios, there is no app equivalent to Pydroid 3 so you need to use a cloud based platform such as PythonAnywhere.